# How can I add a number to the x or y coordinate of the Turtle Pen? [PYTHON]

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I need to be able to move the turtle cursor to its current coordinates +10*y*.

For example, if the turtle is at **(0.00,0.00)** I would need it to read its own coordinates and add 10 to the *y* value making it **(0.00,10.00)**.

I already know how to find the Turtle's current position with turtle.pos() but how would I add an integer onto any given axis?

Comment: Have you read the documentation?  Turtles have `setx` and `sety` methods.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html

Answer (score 1):

Wait nevermind I just found out I can use xcor() and ycor() with setx() and sety()

example:

```
current_y = t.ycor()
t.sety(current_y + 10)
```

this moves the cursor 10 up from its current position

Answer (score 0):

Use turtle.setpos(), Here is The Documentation from GeeksOfGeeks, [Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/turtle-setpos-and-turtle-goto-functions-in-python/)

Full Guide!